# Getting method name from Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, type-conversion

Given the following method signature:

```
string GetActionName<TController, T1, TResult>(Expression<Func<TController, Func<T1, TResult>>> expression)
```

How can I get the method name from the following implementation:

```
GetActionName<EventsController, int, IEnumerable<EventDto>>(c => c.GetEventsByIdLocation);
```

Where `GetEventsById` has the signature of:

```
IEnumerable<EventDto> GetEventsByIdLocation(int id)
```

My current attempt is giving me the exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpressionN' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression'.

```
var convertExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)convertExpression.Operand;
return memberExpression.Member.Name;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that in your call, you are not actually calling the method, but returning it. This caused the expression tree to contain a call to a method called `CreateDelegate`.
Once we have that in our `methodCallExpression` we need to extract the object, and read its value, which is your method.

Disclaimer: This worked for me with a scenario that I think was equal to yours. If it, however, is the best way to solve the larger problem I do not know. It seems to be fairly slow.

```
var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
var constantExpression = (ContantExpression)methodCallExpression.Object;
var methodInfo = (MethodInfo)constantExpression.Value;
return methodInfo.Name
```

Another option would be to provide an actual method call to the method, like so:

```
GetActionName<EventsController, IEnumerable<EventDto>>(
    c => c.GetEventsByIdLocation(0));
```

Which would require you to change the method to:

```
string GetActionName<TController, TResult>(
    Expression<Func<TController, TResult>> expression)
{
    return ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method.Name;
}
```

This solution will probably perform a lot faster. Allthough I havn't done any benchmarks or anything. Also, this option does not tie you to only being able to get the names of methods that take one int parameter.

Comment: No. That results in the exception - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression'

Comment: Oh sorry, I somewhat misread your question. I have a solution, updating the question now!

Comment: This is what I was trying to do but wasn't sure of the conversion types. It looks promising, I'll give it a whirl and let you know. Thanks pcm2

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Been stuck on this for a while now. Thanks again pcm2 :>